# Submitted form details into JSON via PHP and sent to server

Tags: php, json

I've created a few PHP API files that takes submitted form information and compile it as a string and sent the information to a web server via cURL e.g.:

```
$FirstName = $_GET['firstname'];
$LastName = $_GET['lastname'];
$PhoneNumber = $_GET['phone'];
$EmailAddress = $_GET['email'];

$array = array(
    'FirstName' => $FirstName,
    'LastName' => $LastName,
    'PhoneNumber' => $PhoneNumber,
    'EmailAddress' => $EmailAddress
);

.... etc.
```

I have a client that wants the information to be sent as a JSON file

```
{
    "Client": {
        "Firstname" : "####",
        "LastName" : "####",
        "Contact" : {
            "Phonenumber" : "####",
            "Emailaddress" : "####"
        }
    }
}
```

My questions is:

1. How do I compile JSON in a PHP file (if possible)?

Can it work like this...?

```
{
    "Client": {
        "Firstname" : $FirstName,
        "LastName" : $LastName,
        "Contact" : {
            "Phonenumber" : $PhoneNumber,
            "Emailaddress" : $EmailAddress
        }
    }
}
```

2. How do I take the information and sent it to the server in JSON format via PHP?

Any help, or a link to resource will be wonderful.

I've never worked with JSON before so this is quite new to me.

Comment: return your array with json_encode($array); so it look like your expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `json_encode()` like below'

```
$array = array(
    'Client'=>[
      'FirstName' => $FirstName,
      'LastName' => $LastName,
      'Contact' => ['PhoneNumber' => $PhoneNumber,'EmailAddress' => $EmailAddress]
    ]);
$data = json_encode($array);
```

and  pass this $data to cURL

Answer (score 1):

Copy your $_GET to a new array, add a new `Contact` entry to this array, passing it an array with `Phonenumber` & `Emailaddress` a values, and assign them from your original $_GET, then `json_encode($newArray)` to return a `JSON` representation of the array that can be sent to the server.

```
$payload = $_GET; //If this only contains the data you want to send to the server, otherwise create new array using required values.
$payload['Contact'] = ["Phonenumber" => $payload["Phonenumber"], "Emailaddress" => $payload["Emailaddress"]];
unset($payload["Phonenumber"]);
unset($payload["Emailaddress"]);
//Array is converted to JSON below
$payload = json_encode(["Client" => $payload]);
```